# Is it possible to block unity's input?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-mediaplayer

I have a custom Android plugin to play video over unity. It's all working great.

However, I need to block unity's input because there's a scene running behind the video.

I've tried overriding the onTouchEvent on my Activity to no avail.

> My Activity is extending UnityPlayerActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // return true should consume event
    return true;
}
```

Also, I tried adding a custom view on up of my video player with fill_parent and used onTouchEvent.

I've tried setting onTouchListeners everywhere and it's still not working. I'm not able to stop the propagation.

**ex:**

> unityPlayer is found searching for if (view instanceof UnityPlayer)

```
           unityPlayer.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // return true should consume the event...
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Unity is always getting inputs. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: "I've tried overriding the onTouchEvent on my Activity..."  can you post the code for this?

Comment: Added a quick edit showing some code

Comment: Do you want your scene to be running in the background? Maybe try setting Time.timeScale = 0; to stop the game from doing anything. Then set it back to 1 when your video closes.

Comment: timeScale doesnt affect OnMouseDown/OnMouseUp